# Script for running multiple Make Commands

Tags: shell

I would like to get insight on how to get started or what general direction to look in when trying to make a script or makefile that will run 3 make commands at once that take in the same input. These three commands all ask for the same input but just output different excel files due to it manipulating the pulled data in different ways. Therefore If I were able to create a script or makefile that ran all three commands at once when giving the input one time it would SAVE ME A TON OF TIME.

This is all being done in putty pretty much (in terms of the commands)

Thanks,
NP

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a shell script.

For instance, you can create `run.sh` with:

```
#!/bin/bash
make FLAG1=ON $*
make FLAG2=ON $*
make FLAG3=ON $*
```

Make it executable and do `./run.sh MYCOMMOFLAG1=ON MYCOMMONFLAG2=OFF...